# How to replace tags on git remote repo with those on local repo in one command

Tags: git

I'm trying to use below command:

```
git push --force --tags REMOTE master
```

It pushes the code and tags but does not delete existing/old tags on REMOTE. In other words if there is a tag that is not in local but is in REMOTE it won't be deleted by above command.

Is this the intended behaviour of above command?

I'm really confused, I would swear in the past it completely replaced all the tags on REMOTE but now it's not.

Background of the problem:

**git tag** returns eg. tags A B and C

**git ls-remote --tags REMOTE** returns A B C and D

I execute **git push --force --tags REMOTE master** but after that ls-remote still returns A B C and D (D is not deleted)

My workaround is to use **git push --mirror REMOTE** but I just want to check why it does not work with --force --tags

Comment: To delete remote tags you must explicitly ask to delete the specific tags that you do not want: `git push --delete tags/D`

Answer (score 0):

[edit] I initially wrote an answer stating "here is the doc to [--tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---tags) and [--mirror](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror)"

While re-reading said documentation, I realized there is also a [`--prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---tags) option for `git push` (I thought this option was only there for `git fetch`).

For safety: keep a copy of your initial remote references:

```
git ls-remote origin > refs-backup.txt
```

which should allow you to restore these references if you delete some of them accidentally,
you may then try:

```
git push origin --tags --prune
```